# Replace text part before element with JavaScript/JQuery

Tags: jquery, dom

I have a given text with t-tags before some words. Inside the t-tags is the id of the word before the tag, which I have to find and replace with some html-code. What I have so far seems too complicated and also does not work, because the replaced html is printed as text and not as html.

Anybody an idea of a better, easier and working solution?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fsdx2o7h/18/

```
This is the first<t>element1</t>. This is the second<t>element2</t>. This is the third<t>element3</t>.
```

```js
$('t').each(function() {
        var prevText = this.previousSibling.nodeValue;
        var arrPrevText = prevText.split(' ');
        var nrElements = arrPrevText.length;
        var textpart = arrPrevText[nrElements-1];
        var id = $(this).html();
        arrPrevText[nrElements-1] = "<span id='" + id + "'>" + textpart + "</span>";
        this.previousSibling.nodeValue = arrPrevText.join(' ');
    });
```

Comment: I think you want to replace `element1` with `<span id="1">element</span>`. Is that right?

Comment: Not exactly, element1 should be the id of the text part right before the opening t-tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be a bit simpler, yes, but you were on the right track. See comments:

```js
$('t').each(function() {
  // Get our previous sibling
  var prev = this.previousSibling;
  // If not a text node, quit
  if (prev.nodeType !== 3) {
    return;
  }
  // Get the text of it
  var text = prev.nodeValue;
  // Find the last word; if none, quit
  var index = text.lastIndexOf(" ");
  if (index < 0){
    return;
  }
  // Skip past the space prior to the word
  ++index;
  // Grab the word
  var word = text.substring(index).trim();
  // Remove it from the text node
  prev.nodeValue = text.substring(0, index);
  // Replace this `t` element with a span using
  // the word as its text and this `t` element's
  // innerHTML as its ID
  $(this).replaceWith(
    $("<span>").text(word).attr("id", this.innerHTML)
  );
});
```

```css
span[id] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
This is the first<t>element1</t>. This is the second<t>element2</t>. This is the third<t>element3</t>.
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

While you've already accepted an answer I though I'd post what I feel is a slightly simpler alternative (note that I'm unsure as to whether or not the `<t>` element should be removed or not):

```
// selecting the <t> elements, and using the before()
// method to insert new contents ahead of each of the
// elements in the collection:
$('t').before(function() {

  // caching the 'this' (the current <t> element):
  var cached = this,

    // finding the previous sibling of the current
    // <t> element:
    prevNode = cached.previousSibling,

    // splitting that previous textNode (without first
    // checking that it is a textNode, this will lead
    // to errors in live code if you're working with
    // unanticipated structures) into two textNodes
    // at the index of the last index of a white-space,
    // adding 1 to that index in order that we get the
    // last word, without the space character, into its
    // own textNode:
    newPrevNode = prevNode.splitText(prevNode.nodeValue.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1),

    // creating a <span> element:
    span = document.createElement('span');

  // setting the id of the new <span> element to the
  // text of the current <t> element, after first
  // removing leading and trailing white-space
  // using String.prototype.trim():
  span.id = cached.textContent.trim();

  // appending the newPrevNode to the <span>:
  span.appendChild(newPrevNode);

  // returning the created <span> to the method for
  // insertion ahead of the current <t> element:
  return span;

// I'm unsure if you want to remove the <t> elements, if
// you do we can do that using the remove() method (the
// before() method returns the original collection, not
// the newly-inserted elements); if you don't want to
// remove the <t> elements simply omit the call to remove():
}).remove();
```

```js
$('t').before(function() {
  var cached = this,
    prevNode = cached.previousSibling,
    newPrevNode = prevNode.splitText(prevNode.nodeValue.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1),
    span = document.createElement('span');

  span.id = cached.textContent.trim();
  span.appendChild(newPrevNode);

  return span;

}).remove();
```

```css
span {
  color: #f90;
}
span::after {
  content: ' (#' attr(id)') ';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
This is the first
<t>element1</t>. This is the second
<t>element2</t>. This is the third
<t>element3</t>.
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/fsdx2o7h/20/).

The above approach uses a relatively minimal amount of jQuery, but requires jQuery nonetheless; below is a plain JavaScript alternative:

```
// converting the NodeList returned by document.querySelectorAll() into
// an Array, using Array.from(); and iterating over that Array of <t>
// elements using Array.prototype.forEach():
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('t')).forEach(function(elem) {
  // 'elem' : a reference to the current array-element of the
  //          array over which we're iterating.

  // caching that array-element (partially this is laziness since it
  // meant I could assign the variable here and not have to change
  // 'cached' to 'elem' in copying from the above jQuery snippet):
  var cached = elem,

    // retrieving the previousSibling, the textNode:
    prevNode = cached.previousSibling,

    // splitting that textNode into two textNodes at the index,
    // plus one, of the last white-space character; this returns
    // the newly-created textNode (the one 'broken off' from the
    // existing textNode):
    newPrevNode = prevNode.splitText(prevNode.nodeValue.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1),

    // creating a <span> element:
    span = document.createElement('span');

  // setting the id of the <span> to the text of the
  // current <t> element, after first removing
  // leading and trailing white-space using
  // String.prototype.trim():
  span.id = cached.textContent.trim();

  // appending the newly-created/'broken off'
  // textNode to the <span>:
  span.appendChild(newPrevNode);

  // using Node.insertBefore() to insert the
  // <span> ahead of the current <t> element:
  cached.parentNode.insertBefore(span, cached);

  // using Node.removeChild() to remove the
  // current <t> element from the DOM; again:
  // omit this line if you wish to retain
  // the <t> elements in the DOM:
  cached.parentNode.removeChild(cached);

});
```

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('t')).forEach(function(elem) {
  var cached = elem,
    prevNode = cached.previousSibling,
    newPrevNode = prevNode.splitText(prevNode.nodeValue.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1),
    span = document.createElement('span');

  span.id = cached.textContent.trim();
  span.appendChild(newPrevNode);

  cached.parentNode.insertBefore(span, cached);

  cached.parentNode.removeChild(cached);

});
```

```css
span {
  color: #f90;
}
span::after {
  content: ' (#' attr(id)') ';
}
```

```html
This is the first
<t>element1</t>. This is the second
<t>element2</t>. This is the third
<t>element3</t>.
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/fsdx2o7h/21/).

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement).
  - [`Node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild).
  - [`Node.insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore).
  - [`Node.nodeValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeValue).
  - [`Node.parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode).
  - [`Node.previousSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/previousSibling).
  - [`Node.removeChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild).
  - [`String.prototype.lastIndexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf).
  - [`String.prototype.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim).
  - [`Text.splitText()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text/splitText).
- jQuery:

  - [`before()`](http://api.jquery.com/before/).
  - [`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/).

Comment: Great solution David! Perhaps the best so far with most details. I'll give the plain javascript alternative a try the next days, it's probably the fastest one.

Comment: I'm glad to have helped! Bear in mind that the plain JavaScript solution uses an es6 method, `Array.from()`, which may cause problems for users with older browsers.